# How to conserve the Dictionary structure after the filtration of linq

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

```
public class MyClass
{
    public DateTime Date;
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public decimal Close { get; set; }
}
```

Suppose

```
Dictionary<string, List<MyClass>> A
```

I want to filter the `Date` for each `Symbol`(recent N day's data) by `linq`, but I want to conserve the `Dictionary<string, List<MyClass>>` structure after the filtration.

What I can do is just building the `Dictionary` again

```
Dictionary<string, List<MyClass>> C = new Dictionary<string, List<MyClass>>();
var temData = A.Select(o => o.Value.Where(p => p.Date < today).Take(N)).SelectMany(o => o).GroupBy(o => o.Symbol);
foreach (var item in temData)
{
    C.Add(item.Key, item.ToList());
}
```

Is there any simple way such like `ToDictionary` to build the result?

Comment: @GiladGreen sorry, pls the update A is B.

Comment: What is the key? Is it already the `Symbol`? Are the two dictionaries basically the same just that `C` has the filtered items in it?

Comment: @GiladGreen yeah the key is still `Symbol` and I want build a new dictionary but not rewrite `A.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your original dictionary already "groups" by `Symbol` just project a new dictionary out of it but filter the `Value` collection:

```
A = C.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, 
                   pair => pair.Value.Where(i => i.Date < today).Take(N).ToList());
```

---

Notice that if you want the `N` recent items then you need to also order them first:

```
pair.Value.Where(i => i.Date < today).OrderByDescending(i => i.Date).Take(N).ToList()
```